# Virtuemart 2 payment method

Tags: paypal, payment-gateway, virtuemart, joomla1.7, payment-processing

I've installed virtuemart 2 on joomla 1.7. Usually, there are pre-installed payment mthods you can enable to accept payments on your website, but vm 2 has nothing. I thought they would atleast have paypal. It seems like the framework has changed because the VM 1 version of any of the payment gateway modules do not work. I've searched the net for individual downloads of payment gateway modules for vm2, but I cannot find anything, not even paypal. Does anybody have a link to a working payment gateway module for vm2, it doesnt matter which gateway it is, as long as it works?

Answer (score 1):

VirtueMart 2.0 was released without PayPal or many other extensions. Given that it's a complete re-write and aims to use Joomla!'s MVC and framework as much as possible, it means that payment, shipping etc all have to be re-written as Joomla! plug-ins to work.

VirtueMartt 2.0.1 is in development and due out shortly it includes the first Payment plugins including PayPal.  You can [read more about it here.](http://forum.virtuemart.net/index.php?topic=96945.0)

For future reference the best places are the [VirtueMart Extensions Directory](http://extensions.virtuemart.net/index.php?option=com_sobi2&catid=1&Itemid=2) (which appears to show several working 2.0 payment plug-ins). You can also discover new [VirtueMart extensions](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension-specific/virtuemart-extensions) is the [Joomla! Extension Directory (JED)](http://extensions.joomla.org/)

Answer (score 1):

> Planetauthorize provides a free module that supports VirtueMart 2
>
> http://planetauthorize.com/virtuemart.html

That page only has a pdf for the VM 2 link.

I'm also looking for a paypal payment extension for VM 2

Answer (score 0):

You have to install the AIO modules, and enable them in the extensions menu in joomla. Some payments options include paypal pro , and paypal normal.

Best Regards.

Answer (score 0):

There are already 4 plugins of vm for payment in vm2. They are now installed in joomla plugins folder under vmpayment. To use them simply click new in the vm2 admin and select payment method as VM-payment paypal.
Hope this helps.